# Is it possible to use ReSharper as a test runner ONLY?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, resharper, test-explorer

I don't really like ReSharper (let's not go into that), but it's test runner is way better than VS default Test Explorer. For example, VS doesn't handle tests polymorphism well (or even at all), while ReSharper does. 
Is it possible to install and configure ReSharper in a way that it will be totally turned off except for it's test runner?

Comment: What is it about ReSharper you dislike? If it's just the test runner you want then you could try NCrunch (http://www.ncrunch.net/) which will continuously run your tests for you in the background.

Comment: @PiersMyers I don't need to run tests in the background, I just need the runner to handle test classes polymorphism.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider installing JetBrains dotCover https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover. It is the same test runner as in ReSharper.

Comment: Glad to hear that!